# Multiselect dropdown closing after one select

Tags: vue.js, dropdown, multi-select

I have a multi-select dropdown for listing and selecting some items.
I am using the following code for the multi-select dropdown.

```
     <Multiselect
            v-model="abc"
            valueProp="xyz"
            label="userName"
            mode="multiple"
            placeholder="Select Recipients"
            class="multiselect-blue"
            :hideSelected="false"
            :options="recipients"
          >
     </Multiselect>
```

the problem is when I select one option, the dropdown closes.
I want to close the drop-down only after selecting options as much I want.
is there any way to implement that

Answer (score 1):

set the on close select property to false like

```
:close-on-select="false",
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps you out, but just use:

`<multiple/>` without the `mode=`

Than it's not a real dropdown it's a multi selection field..

Comment: just for additional info! Using ```:value``` will make you able to choose only one selection!

Comment: problem resolved by adding  :closeOnSelect="false"